# DependsUponMavenPlugin when upgrading SonarQube to 5.1

Tags: sonarqube

When upgrading SonarQube to 5.1 from 4.4 I get the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/api/batch/maven/DependsUponMavenPlugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.plugins.clirr.ClirrPlugin.getExtensions(ClirrPlugin.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerExtensionInstaller.installExtensions(ServerExtensionInstaller.java:51) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerComponents.startLevel4Components(ServerComponents.java:819) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:120) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.batch.maven.DependsUponMavenPlugin
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227) ~[plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:na]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

SonarQube the fails to load and the wrapper then stops running. The database upgrade also failed because of this error.

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: The error has progressed to Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: QProfile is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using an outdated version of the CLIRR plugin, please update to the latest 1.2 release.

Comment: Thanks I have upgraded all of the plug-ins and the error has been moved on